# To have project in project in GIT

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have created GIT project in BitBucket and repository in it. And just wondering why I can't have project2 in project1 and repository1 in project2?

```
Project1
|
--Project2
  |  
  --Repository1
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/projects-792497956.html) is Atlassian's official documentation on the topic.

Projects on Bitbucket are used to group repositories, what would be the difference between a repository and a project if projects could contain projects?

Let's say your team is developing software for a shop. The shop owner wants to enable online shopping for his clients and also have a mobile application that does the same thing as web app. So you create a project "MyShop", and then you put two modules (repositories) in it "MyShopWebApp" and "MyShopAndroidApp". Android application will obviously have to deal with API of web application, so it's a good reason to group them into one project, at the same time allowing two teams of developers to work on them independently.